# Interpreting the latent growth model output

Tags: self-study, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, growth-model

I started to go through this interesting structural equation model called latent growth curve model.

When i go through some research articles that involved latent growth curve models, I found this diagram. [image]

I understood that the transmissible liability index variables are the repeated variables which used to find the latent slope and intercept.

My question is about other variables. Are those variables are response variables? 
Also in the factor loading there some letters (ex: 0.36c -0.16a) . What are those letters refers to ?  The paper that included this diagram didn't specifically mentioned about these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are response (outcome) variables. They are saying that the intercept and slope predict these variables.

I have no idea what a and c mean, this is not standard notation.

The model is drawn slightly unconventionally and is lacking in details.

For anyone else looking, this is the paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4630111/